# Does "onion" have a (proper) verb form?

Tags: verbs

I was trying to figure out a little about an Italian children's book character called Cipollino.  The character is an anthropomorphic onion. I had been aware of cipolla in Italian, as well as diminutive forms, as well as cebula, in Polish.  I went down a rabbit hole and discovered that, contrary to my expectations Russian went for the more Germanic лук, a cognate with leek or German *lauch*. The rabbit hole got deeper, but Google translate stopped me in my tracks with:
[image]

Does anybody have an idea what the verb they might be referring to is?  My suspicion is that, in Russian, these words might say something like "smother it with onions", much like some of my friends like to say "bacon it" to mean that it would taste better with some bacon.  However, I don't really picture "to onion (something)" legitimate, either as a transitive or intransitive verb. I would not expect this to be considered standard enough to come up on Google translate, though I fault the engine with much worse, perhaps somebody has some ready examples.

Comment: "приправлять" means to flavour or to season, so I suppose it means "to flavour with onion"

Comment: There is no “to onion” in English, unless it is a new usage. Are you asking what “to onion” means in Russian?

Comment: I am asking whether the Google translate example I gave above reflects a reality in English. These two Russian phrases are translated as verbs, and as "onion".  I have never seen or heard onion as a verb, but I am not all-knowing, so I thought I'd ask here.

Comment: @Ben Mansley - yes, I had gotten that far, but usual practice in Google translate is to give an explanation to a phrase, rather than a one word translation (that doesn't work), so I was wondering if there is a usage I am not aware of.

Comment: Let's sneakily make that usage popular ... heavily onioned soup, sounds good!

Comment: Any noun in English can be used as a verb.

Comment: @Clare, yes, but they don't all get "listed" as verbs.

Comment: For what it's worth, _OED_ lists the verb _onion_ but adds that it is rare. Here are the two definitions listed:

 **1.** *trans.* To season or flavour with onions. Cf. onioned *adj.* 2.
 **2.** *trans.* To treat (the eyes) with raw onion, so as to produce tears. Also in extended use. Cf. onioned *adj.* 1.

Comment: That seems to follow, exactly, the two Russian examples.  Seems the English is more concise than the Russian, frequency aside. Thanks!

I'm surprised there doesn't seem to be a usage that encapsulates the idea of "peeling something like an onion", as in layer after layer.

Answer (score 4):

приправлять луком means *flavour with onions* while натирать себе глаза луком means *rub onions in your eyes*

I have never used *onion* as a verb, but the first is implicit in the use of [*onioned* as an adjective given by Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/onioned)

> Of food: cooked or served with onions, containing onions.

while George Bernard Shaw used the eye irritation sense in the [preface to *Three Plays for Puritans*](https://archive.org/stream/forpur00shawthreeplaysrich#page/n33/mode/2up)

> But when your Shakespears and Thackerays huddle up the matter at the end by killing somebody and covering your eyes with the undertaker's handkerchief, duly onioned with some pathetic phrase, as The flight of angels sing thee to thy rest, or Adsum, or the like, I have no respect for them at all : such maudlin tricks may impose on tea-drunkards, not on me.

Comment: Thanks for the example.  I find this "onioned" an easy interpretation which follows the meaning of *приправлять луком*, but it does very little to reconcile *натирать себе глаза луком*. Now, if there was an example of an actor asking to be onioned in preparation for a crying scene, we'd be all set - with examples that hardly make the usage standard.

Comment: It is not true that if there is an *-ed* of something, it must have been a verb. There is also the *-ed* suffix that is applied to nouns to form adjectives, like *snaggle-toothed* or *rose-breasted*.

Comment: @tchrist: those examples might be more persuasive if *breast* and *tooth* were not also verbs

Comment: **OED:** “The suffix is now added without restriction to any n. from which it is desired to form an adj. with the sense ‘possessing, provided with, characterized by’ (something); e.g. in *toothed, booted, wooded, moneyed, cultured, diseased, jaundiced,* etc., and in parasynthetic derivatives, as *dark-eyed, seven-hilled, leather-aproned,* etc. In *bigoted, crabbed, dogged,* the suffix has a vaguer meaning.”